# Line with equations and text

Tags: text

I would like to have a line with both equations and text, but the math environment takes over.  What can I do so that I can include text in the equation display ?

Comment: Welcome. // Just tried my telepathic skill to read your code, but failed unfortunately ...

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid your question is a bit too vague to get an answer. Can you please add an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[italian,10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Text with equation $E=mc^2$ followed by text and $x=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x^+2}$.\\
    Another line of text.
\end{document}
```

or like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[italian,10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Text with equation $E=mc^2$ followed by text and $x=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x^+2}$.\\
    Another line of text.\\
    Equation with text:
    
    \[ x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \quad\text{solution of:}\quad ax^2+bx+c=0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would have gone with `flalign` for more controll over the location and spacing.